# CSS background images with and without links and accessibility

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, wcag

I'm using images inside `div` containers with css(background images). Not just for presentation, they have meanings. I want to provide alternatives to users with disabilities, but not sure how to do this right. I also use them inside links sometimes, this is also needed to be addressed somehow.

With case one(images inside `div` with css, but without link), I thought of using hidden text inside of `div`, but not sure if I should specify that this is the image and not just a text. Because when text alternative provided for images, disabled user will see that this text is belong to the image(with `aria-labelledby` for example), so how should this be done with `div` and css image?

With the second case, I also not sure how to make it right. I want to use `title` for the link, so the normal users will also benefit from this by hovering mouse for icons, for example, but I'm not really sure if `title` will suffice for disabled people.

Comment: Barring some specfic examples and context (like a web page), these three links may be useful to you: http://webaim.org/techniques/alttext/#background, https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/, http://adrianroselli.com/2016/12/accessible-emoji-tweaked.html

Comment: Thanks aadrian, I will take a look at it. You have nice website btw :) Informative.

Answer (score 0):

That's clearly what `role=img` is for:

```
<a href="...">
  <div role="img" class="css_classename"
       aria-label="This information is provided to a screen reader"
       title="This is a tooltip">
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Adam, that's great! But what if I want to use also some content inside `role="img"` `div`? Would it be valid? If no, what if I'll use another `div` inside the `role="img"` `div`?

Comment: It's valid HTML, but relating to ARIA, the `aria-label` will take precedence on any text contained inside.

Comment: @sorvz [`role=img`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#img) is only a fit if the _entire_ element is to be treated as an image. Avoid using it if you will have nested content unless you have a good understanding how it works and are going to test with screen readers. As I mentioned in my comment above, seeing some examples would help. One code solution rarely works for all scenarios. IMO, this solution has limited utility.